# Live Agent Credit Card Question - Two Part

Tags: liveagent

I am trying to accomplish two things with live agent that shouldn't be TOO difficult but I can't find the solution anywhere...

1. We want to be able to accept credit cards, so we need live agent to NOT save credit card numbers in the transcript for PCI compliance. How would I go about doing this?
2. We want the agents to be able to click the credit card number in the chat window, and have it populate the card number - because we don't let agents cut and paste.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for some code that would accomplish this?

Neither one of these should be a new request - but it seems there are no apps that do anything with this.  UGH!  :)

Comment: Number one should be fairly simple, just pass the credit card number as a custom detail in the chat. 
Regarding number 2, what do you mean by clicking on the credit card number should populate the card number, where are you populating this information?

Comment: Can "custom details" be used IN the chat?  For instance, chat is going on, a product is sold, and then they want to collect the credit card in the middle of the chat - how would we use that.

Comment: The only I see that being possible is by copy/pasting from the chat window.

Comment: Okay, so back to my original question - is there a way I can mod the transcript to remove the credit card from it?  :)

Comment: Custom details are not stored by default in the transcript so if you are seeing it there is because in your code your saving it to the transcript.

Comment: Oh, I get that - but I can't get the custom details IN the chat - that has to be done on a prechat window right?  So they would have to give their credit card up front?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but you could leverage Chargent and the Payment requests where the agent would sent a payment request to the customer, they would click the link enter their information and boom payment collected (PCI Compliant). Just throwing it out there and it would require some customization....

Answer (score 0):

Custom details are not saved unless you specify it, so you just need to ensure you are not saving it in the code.

If you want the credit card information to be available as a "custom detail" in the chat window, you would need to capture that before the chat starts, either using the pre-chat form (pre-chat API) or the deployment API.  You can then use the **getdetails()** method to retrieve this information from the chat window which you would have to build. See "Accessing Chat Details for your Visualforce Chat Window" in the Live Agent Developer Guide

[http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index.htmGuide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index.htm)